# Javascript Signal R error thrown when using multiple tabs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, signalr

I am using SignalR.

When I open multiple tabs of my web site and test simultaneously I get the following error:

> WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Any idea what would cause this and how I would log it or fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more information. How do you connect to your hub? And show the server implementation of your hub...

Comment: adding more logging before I post more info... will elaborate soon